Cannot call route action when using createRemixStub
I have a route with a loader, and action, and a component. (the second argument to the loader and action are for providing mock services when calling them from tests. I'm sure I can do this with AppLoadContext but I'll get to that in the future). You can see that the action is obviously a diagnostic stub, but you'll see my problem later.
export async function loader(_args: LoaderFunctionArgs, _emailService?: EmailService) {
  const emailService = _emailService ?? new EmailFixtureService();
  // do stuff
  return json({ eventRowsJson });
}


export async function action(args: ActionFunctionArgs, distanceService?: DistanceService) {
  console.log("BEFORE BEFORE BEFORE");
  await distanceService?.getDistanceInfo({
    from: "",
    to: ""
  });
  console.log("AFTER AFTER AFTER");
  return { hello: "world" };
}

export default function Events() {
  const { eventRowsJson } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  return <EventsPage eventRows={eventRowsJson} />;
};

The EventsPage basically renders this tree:

eventRows.map

<FullGigUI />

<GetDistanceInfoButton />





function GetDistanceInfoButton({ location }: { location: string }) {
  return (
    <form method="post" >
      <input name="location" type="hidden" value={location} />
      <Button data-testid="GET_DISTANCE_INFO_BUTTON">
        Get distance info
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}

export function Button(props: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & { "data-testid"?: string }) {
  return (
    <div className="grid place-items-center h-full" data-testid={props["data-testid"] ?? "saveButton"}>
      <button type="submit" className="p-2 bg-gray-200 border-black border">
        {props.children}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

I've set up a remix stub to test the following flow:

The page renders with two "events", neither of which have distance data
Click "Get Distance Info" button
The action fetches the distance info from the DistanceService
The route shows the distance info

I got the loader and the page working and then started writing these TDD tests below, with the basically dummy action you see above. I used createRemixStub, and the loader works but I can't get the action to work. I can't figure out if I'm defining the action wrong, or using fireEvent wrong (I've also tried (getDistanceInfoButtons[0] as HTMLButtonElement).click()), or something else entirely.
I set up the loader and action spies to help diagnose whether I'm using createRemixStub correctly. I don't think the actual route action is any kind of problem (yet) because loaderSpy is being called, but actionSpy is not, inside or outside of waitFor (and debug breakpoints inside the stub functions bear out the same thing). Once I get the stubbed action working I'll scrap the loader/action spies and assert on calls to DistanceService calls and then keep building my test and functionality.
I can load the page in the browser and clicking the button definitely triggers the action. I've also tried moving the data-testid to the button itself, and providing the action argument to the form in GetDistanceInfoButton (again, leaving it as default works in the browser, but I noticed when debugging the test that the formAction is localhost:3000/ -- setting the path correctly made it the right path in the debugger, but both the browser and the test work/don't-work the same either way.
it("Fetches the distance info and updates the event ui", async () => {
  const RemixStub = createRemixStub([
    {
      path: EventsRoute.PATH,
      loader: (args) => EventsRoute.loader(args, new EmailServiceMock()),
      action: (args) => EventsRoute.action(args, mockDistanceService),
      Component: eventsRoute
    }
  ]);

  const loaderSpy = vi.spyOn(EventsRoute, "loader");
  const actionSpy = vi.spyOn(EventsRoute, "action");

  expect(loaderSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  render(<RemixStub initialEntries={[EventsRoute.PATH]} />);
  await waitFor(() => screen.findByTestId("EVENTS_PAGE"));
  expect(loaderSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  const getDistanceInfoButtons = screen.getAllByTestId("GET_DISTANCE_INFO_BUTTON");

  // neither event has distance info yet
  expect(getDistanceInfoButtons).toHaveLength(2);

  expect(mockDistanceService.getDistanceInfo).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  fireEvent.click(getDistanceInfoButtons[0]);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(actionSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // FAIL!!! (with or without waitFor)
  });
});

